# How to calculate distance from hips to hands in Mediapipe/Blazepose (z coordinates)?

Tags: python, depth, mediapipe, pose-estimation

I am working on a project where I detect poses from a stickfigure and I am trying to extract the z coordinates from the landmarks via mediapipe/blazepose.
The next step would be to calculate the distance between the z-coordinate from the hips to the hand and show the value on the image.
[Overview set-up with distance hips-hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdT2c.jpg)

Can someone explain to me how the z coordinate extraction for mediapipe works? And what code I can use for my goal?
I am really new at programming so until now I only made a program that can detect the landmarks and draw them on the image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need the world coordinates. To do that, use `results.pose_world_landmarks` and then the distance of the hand to the hips in z will just be the z coordinate of the hand